# How can I use a named iterator with postfix foreach?

Tags: perl

```
@values = (1..5);

foreach $s(@values){
        print "$s\n";    #It works
 }
 print "$_\n",foreach (@values);  #It also works
 print "$s\n",foreach $s(@values);  #It not works
```

How to give the variable name?
Above the code does not print. It show the syntax error.
How to give the name for the foreach concept in **,** separated syntax. How can i do it.?

Comment: , and () is not required in suffix case.

Comment: @choroba - I'm beginner in perl. Actually my other perl script is foreach(exp){ foreach(exp){ } }. In the middle of the foreach condition i can use statement modifier. I also expect the named iterator for outer of the loop condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to assign a variable name to the [`for`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/for.html) loop iterator when using a [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers):

> #### Statement Modifiers
>
> Any simple statement may optionally be followed by a SINGLE modifier, just before the terminating semicolon (or block ending). The possible modifiers are:
>
> ```
>       ...
>       for LIST
>       foreach LIST
>       ...
> ```
>
> The [`for(each)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/for.html) modifier is an iterator: it executes the statement once for each item in the LIST (with `$_` aliased to each item in turn).
>
> ```
>       print "Hello $_!\n" for qw(world Dolly nurse);
> ```

Instead, as stated above, you must use the [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) variable:

```
@values = (1..5);
print "$_\n" for @values;
```

If you want to use a variable name for the iterator, then simply use a [`for(each)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) in long form:

```
for my $var (@values) {
    print "$var\n";
}
```

Comment: Dear @Miller I not expect this. I know this, but how store the $_ into other variable.

Comment: @Hussain - As he says, you can't as a statement modifier

Comment: Thank you @Miller i get a better idea from your answer.

Comment: @Hussain Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

```
my @values = (1..5);
print "$_\n" foreach (@values);  
__END__
1
2
3
4
5
```

If you *really* want the variable to be named `$s`, you can do this:

```
my @values = (1..5);
print "$s\n" while($s = shift @values);
```

but the first approach is more idiomatic and readable.

Comment: Yes. I wants to rename the $_ with other variable name.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, you can't declare a name for the iterator in a for statement modifier.  But here is a way you can get the similar effect of doing a loop on one line with a named variable.

[perl5i](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5i) provides a number of language enhancements, including this one...

```
use perl5i::2;

@a->foreach(func($s) { say $s });

# Similar to...
print "$_\n" for @a;
```

This also works for grep, map and the notoriously tricky to use correctly "each".

```
%h->each(func($key, $val) { say "$key => $val" });
```

You can also work in pairs, triplets, etc...

```
@a->foreach(func($this,$that) { say "$this, $that" });
```

Performance may suffer as perl5i makes a full function call for each iteration, rather than just a cheaper block entry.

Answer (score 1):

Although I wouldn't recommend this in general due to readability issues, you could temporarily alias another global variable to the `_` variable.

```
{
    our $s;
    local *s = *_;
    print "$s\n" for 1, 2, 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a `do` block and reassign the `$_` variable inside the block:

```
@values = (1..5);

do { $s = $_; print "$s\n" },foreach (@values);
```